# Gradle Configuration for Kotlin Multiplatform Project in Java and Js

Tags: gradle, kotlin, multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

### Seems all ok! But...

I have created a Kotlin Multiplatform Project in Js and Java. I worked on create the right tests for all target and the right configuration for the build. Seems all go right, i managed to create the build and set it in the right way. Today i have opened the project and it stop, the build complete successfull but test and java compilations don't be executed.

**So how i can configure it?**

With code and result all will be more clear

**build.gradle.kts**

```
import com.moowork.gradle.node.npm.NpmTask
import com.moowork.gradle.node.task.NodeTask
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJsCompile

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50")
    }
}

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.50"
    id("com.moowork.node") version "1.3.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1"


kotlin {
    jvm()
    js()
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
    js {
        nodejs()
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        jvm {
            compilations["main"].defaultSourceSet {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                }
            }
            compilations["test"].defaultSourceSet {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("test"))
                    implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                }
            }
        }
        js {
            sequenceOf("", "Test").forEach {
                tasks.getByName<KotlinJsCompile>("compile${it}KotlinJs") {
                    kotlinOptions {
                        moduleKind = "umd"
                        noStdlib = true
                        metaInfo = true
                    }
                }
            }
            compilations["main"].defaultSourceSet {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
                }
            }
            compilations["test"].defaultSourceSet {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
val compileKotlinJs = tasks.getByName("compileKotlinJs")
val compileTestKotlinJs = tasks.getByName("compileTestKotlinJs")

val libDir = "$buildDir/lib"
val compileOutput = compileKotlinJs.getOutputs().getFiles()
val testOutput = compileTestKotlinJs.getOutputs().getFiles()

val populateNodeModules = tasks.create<Copy>("populateNodeModules") {
    afterEvaluate {
        from(compileOutput)
        from(testOutput)

        configurations["testCompile"].forEach {
            if (it.exists() && !it.isDirectory) {
                from(zipTree(it.absolutePath).matching { include("*.js") })
            }
        }
        for (sourceSet in kotlin.sourceSets) {
            from(sourceSet.resources)
        }
        into("$buildDir/node_modules")
    }
    dependsOn("compileKotlinJs")
}

node {
    download = true;
}

tasks.create<NpmTask> ("installJest") {
    setArgs(setOf("install", "jest"))
}

tasks.create<NodeTask> ("runJest") {
    setDependsOn(setOf("installJest", "populateNodeModules", "compileTestKotlinJs"))
    setScript(file("node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"))
    setArgs(compileTestKotlinJs.outputs.files.toMutableList().map {projectDir.toURI().relativize(it.toURI())})
}

tasks.getByName("test").dependsOn("runJest")
```

Look how many task are skiped! and how build Dir is created

[buid result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PivSf.jpg)
[build dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFO7H.png)

I use jest to test in js.
Thanks in advance for support me